# A non-composite sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, recreational-mathematics

Can you provide a counterexample for a claim given below?

Inspired by [Puzzle 937](https://www.primepuzzles.net/puzzles/puzz_937.htm) I have formulated the following claim:

> For any  $n > 0$  let  $B = p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot .... \cdot p_n$   be the product of the first  $n$  primes. Let  $X$  be the smallest number, bigger than  $B^k/p_{n+1}$  and coprime to  $B^k$, where $k$ is a *fixed* positive integer. Define the number  $m_n$  as $X \cdot p_{n+1}-B^k$ , then $m_n$ is either  $1$  or prime.

[Try it for yourself!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFi7EOgzAMRHf-gs0hRiWslhe-IhNDIC0WSUBRUX-_rjqw3d27lwI7ugKPA-2amudRoXAKeAWc-KzHCsIOC55VcgQxhjwvURLANO_m8Z-LdQo-m6QIr2UFjz_YquitNZTZd_exV0ZayxuyWs0XSVknXw==&lang=gp)

I was searching for counterexample using the following PARI/GP code:

```
CE(lb,ub,k)={
for(n=lb,ub,
B=prod(i=1,n,prime(i));
X=ceil((B^k)/prime(n+1));
while(gcd(X,B^k)!=1,
X++);
m=X*prime(n+1)-B^k;
if(!(ispseudoprime(m) || m==1),print(m)))
}
```

Comment: @babanaCats, for $B^1=30$, aren't both $p_{n+1}$ and $X$ equal?

Comment: I found no counterexamples for $1\le n\le 1000$, $1\le k\le 30$.

Comment: @rogerl Thank you for your investigation.

Answer (score 0):

After sieving $p_n$, numbers coprime to the primoral $p_n\#$ are prime at least up to $p_{n+1}^2$ ($1$ and square excluded of course)

e.g. $p_n=5$, numbers coprime to $p_n\#=30=B$ (also coprime to $B^k$) are $\{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,49,...\}$ and are prime up to $49$.

These numbers are generally expressed in this form: $p_n\#\cdot i+\{1,p_{n+1},...\}$

e.g. for $p_n=3$ they are expressed as $$6i+\{1,5\}$$
e.g. for $p_n=5$ they are expressed as $$30i+\{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29\}$$

Obviously, $X$ is coprime to $B^k$ (it was picked in the coprime list) and so is $p_{n+1}$ which means $X\cdot p_{n+1}$ is also coprime to $B^k$(=$30i$ in our example) and since $X\cdot p_{n+1}=B^k+m_n$, we know $m_n$ is in that coprime list.

$m_n=p_{n+1}\cdot x$ where $x=X-\frac{B^k}{p_{n+1}}$ is smaller than the maximum gap between coprimes in the list (since we pick the first smaller coprime greater than $\frac{B^k}{p_{n+1}}$). If this maximum gap is smaller than $p_{n+1}$, then $m_n<p_{n+1}^2$ and is therefore prime or $1$.

I think it was shown that the maximum gap between numbers coprime to $p_n$ is smaller than $p_{n+1}$, but I'll have a look when I have a bit more time.

edit: well....it was not http://oeis.org/A048670

Comment: undelete of a quick try. Too quick in fact, but a failure that might...perhaps....give some ideas. I won't have enought time to dig more.